# What is the effect if I use famous actor's name as the domain name for a classified website?

Tags: seo, domains, legal, local-seo

I want to buy a domain for a classified website.
What happen if I use a famous actor's name who also known in my country as the domain name for my website?

for eg: If I use 
salman khans's ( he is indian actor who knows every one in my country )

first name as domain name

www.salman.lk

what kind of a SEO advantage will I get?

If somebody type just salman sure google will show results of slaman khan's
If somebody type salman.lk will it indexed on google?

What is the legal side of this?

What is your idea?

Comment: Too many questions here. Some are off-topic, some are too broad, and some have been covered here before.

Comment: No issues. you can use it freely.

Answer (score 1):

A negligible amount, because the name does have value, but keywords in domainnames are barely worth anything. Especially when the site isn't about him at all.

The risk is that his lawyers sue you. And if you're making money of his name, that'll be a claim way higher than you'll ever make by using his name.

**Just pick a name related to your site.**

---

[How important is it to have keywords in a domain name? - on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAWFv43qubI)

> As Cutts explains, the key to having a well-ranking website has become less about having certain keywords in the right places and more about having great content that people actually want.

Comment: Anchor text branding helps through! :)